# How to retrieve datetime minus 4 hours in Mule 3

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-el

I'm trying to get the current time minus 4 hours using the dateTime function.
With the next expression:

```
#[server.dateTime.plusHours(-4)format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")]
```

Flow:

```
<sub-flow name="retrieve-time-last-run-os">
        <objectstore:retrieve config-ref="ObjectStore_Connector" key="timeNow" defaultValue-ref="#[server.dateTime.plusHours(-4)format(&quot;yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'&quot;)]" doc:name="Retrieve Time Now"/>
        <set-variable variableName="time" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Save time"/>
</sub-flow>
```

locally it works fine. The problem is when I deploy this function seems not to work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: What version of Mule are you using? 'Does not work' is not very helpful. What is the result?

Comment: I am using mule 3

Comment: I have after that function a set payload which gives an error: Message : Execution of the expression "Payload" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).

Comment: Please add both the XML for where you use the function and the set payload to understand the context. 
What version exactly of Mule 3? Mule 3.9?

Comment: @aled I have added in the question section. Thanks aled

Comment: I posted a possible solution based on the expression in the flow. Note that this is a Mule Expression Language (MEL) expression, not DataWeave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the flow there seem to be a missing dot between plusHours() and format().